# Django Rest Framework - Group data by its parent tag

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Django Rest Framework - Group data by its parent tag

I have 3 serializers, One for tactics, one for techniques, one for sub techniques, and I'll be adding the sub techniques serializer as an explicit field to the techniques serializer.

models

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    _id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self._id

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self._id

class ModelA(models.Model):
    _id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    queries = ArrayField(models.TextField(),null=True, blank=True, default=list)

    def __str__(self):
        return self._id

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self._id

class ModelB(models.Model):
    subtitle = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.subtitle
```

serializers

```
# serializers
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        print(value)
        return value.name

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('name',)

class QueriesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = '__all__'

class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    queries = QueriesSerializer(source='modelb_set', many=True)
    tag = TagSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ('_id','title', 'tag','queries',)


class EndUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data = ??

    class Meta:
        model = ??
        fields = '__all__'
```

I want to create a data visualization API where I need to use the results of ASerializer by their given tag in order to categorize each object into categories based on their associated tag if the object contains two tags, then it should be displayed in both . e.g

desired response

```
{
    [
        {
            "tag": "Biologyl,
            "data":  [
                {
                    "_id": str
                    "title": str
                    "tag": []
                    "queries": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "Denoi2,
            "data":  [
                {
                    "_id": str
                    "title": str
                    "tag": []
                    "queries": []
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

actual response

```
{
    "_id": str
    "title": str
    "tag": []
    "queries": []
}
```

viewset

```
#viewsets   
class BooksViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                      viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    queryset = ??.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EndUserSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `django-rest-multiple-models` for receiving multiple querysets in the same view.

https://github.com/MattBroach/DjangoRestMultipleModels

It should look like this:

```
class BooksViewSet(ObjectMultipleModelAPIView):
    querylist = [
        {
            'querylist': ModelA.objects.filter(tags__name="Biologyl"),
            'serializer_class': EndUserSerializer,
            'label': 'Biologyl',
        },
        {
            'querylist': ModelA.objects.filter(tags__name="Denoi2"),
            'serializer_class': EndUserSerializer,
            'label': 'Denoi2',
        },
        ....
    ]
```

You can also make it dynamic, but it seems a little bit dangerous.

```
class BooksViewSet(ObjectMultipleModelAPIView):
    querylist = [
        {
            'querylist': ModelA.objects.filter(tags=tag),
            'serializer_class': EndUserSerializer,
            'label': tag.name,
        }
        for tag in Tag.objects.all()
    ]
```

See more https://django-rest-multiple-models.readthedocs.io/en/latest/object-options.html